# Controlling sqrts (mathptmx)

Tags: mathptmx, sqrt

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass[border=10mm,varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{2+(n+2)^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

As it stands with CM fonts we get

[image]

Adding `mathptmx` we get

[image]

Which is really horrible, especially it it scales like that in the text.

Any ideas on how to better control `\sqrt` with `mathptmx` (and no we cannot change the font package, it is what the publisher is using). Note that I'd like to not have to deal with a lot of messing with phantoms.

Comment: well, that's a bummer.  it looks to me like the font size used for superscripts with times is just a tad larger than the computer modern setting, with the result that a superscript digit kicks the total height above the `\sqrt`-sizing threshold.  try using (top) `\smash` on the superscript.  (haven't tried it myself, so don't know if there will be side effects.)

Comment: well, i did just try it; running under tex live 2012.  and that doesn't happen -- the radical is the same relative size as for cm.  likewise for tex live 2015.  (we don't have 2016 installed yet.)

Answer (score 5):

The superscript to the parenthesis triggers using the second “next larger” character for the square root, not the first one like with CM. I guess it has to do with the height+depth of the parentheses.

You can smash the superscript.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm,varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{2+(n+2)^{\smash{2}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is the same with NewTX, I'm afraid; with MTPro2 it comes out right without smashing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also trick `sqrt` by making the argument smaller and the entire square root bigger. This has the advantage of not having to adjust individual equations.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm,varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\sqroot}[1]{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sqrt{\mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{#1}}}}}}
\begin{document}
Original:
\[
\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{2+(n+2)^2}
\]

New:
\[
\sqroot{n+1}\sqroot{2+(n+2)^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]